# WPF C# UserControl DependencyProperty Command Binding is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, viewmodel, commandbinding

I created a `UserControl` as a file browsing tool and I wanted to implement `Commands` as `DependencyProperties` for loading and saving so that I can bind `Commands` from my `ViewModel` in order to handle them.

The problem now is that if I use the predefined `Commands` like `Open` or `Save`  and handle them in my `Window` it works but if I use `Bindings`from my `ViewModel` these `Commands`are `null`...

The following code is an example program where I removed everything that is not important for my question because it would have been way too much code.

---

### UserControl

#### XAML

```cs
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.TestControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         xmlns:models="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Models"
         Height="21" Width="80" Margin="2">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <models:UserControlViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource ViewModel}"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="_Load" IsDefault="True"
            Command="{Binding Path=ExecuteCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=LoadCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType ={x:Type local:TestControl}}}"/>
</Grid>
```

#### Code-Behind

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class TestControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LoadCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LoadCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public ICommand LoadCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(LoadCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LoadCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public TestControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Prism.Commands;

namespace WpfApplication1.Models
{
    public class UserControlViewModel
        : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public DelegateCommand<ICommand> ExecuteCommand { get; }
        private void ExecuteCommand_Executed(ICommand cmd) => cmd?.Execute("C:\\Test.txt");

        private void Notify([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            if (name != null)
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public UserControlViewModel()
        {
            ExecuteCommand = new DelegateCommand<ICommand>(ExecuteCommand_Executed);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Window

#### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Models"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
    <Window.Resources>
        <models:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource ViewModel}"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Open" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <local:TestControl LoadCommand="{Binding Path=OpenCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"/>
        <local:TestControl LoadCommand="Open"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

#### Code-Behind

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Window: {e.Parameter.ToString()}");
        }
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using Prism.Commands;

namespace WpfApplication1.Models
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public DelegateCommand<string> OpenCommand { get; }
        private void OpenCommand_Executed(string file)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Model: {file}");
        }

        private void Notify([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            OpenCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(OpenCommand_Executed);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The window includes a predefined `Open Command` to that that this way works but the `Binding` does not.

In order to run this application you need the Prism.Wpf NuGet package.

Comment: Shoot me a reply when you get the MVCE posted. It shouldn't be that hard once I've got the full picture.

Comment: You didn't assign the command in the ViewModel.  If you're using the one posted it is null.  Also, the command work should exist in the ViewModel at this point and you're still using code behind for the command.  Basically, if you want to add a command to the control then just create the ICommand in a custom control wrapping the Browser (copy the code in ViewModel there) or put the logic in the ViewModel.  If I'm wrong post all the code please so that I can see the full picture.

Comment: `Shoot me a reply` - it is done by using @EdPlunkett - a name with `at` character in the comment.

Comment: Thank you @Vojtěch Dohnal .

Comment: @Michael Puckett II now you can see the full picture.

Comment: @dukemadcat Updated my answer. Not a tough fix at all. Your design with the commands is sound; it's just that you went about setting up the viewmodels and bindings the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you fished up something odd out of the depths here. But to paraphrase a friend of mine, "The good news is, the cancer is easier to treat this time".

First I biopsied your binding using `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel`:

```
<local:TestControl 
    LoadCommand="{Binding 
                    Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, 
                    Path=OpenCommand, 
                    PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" 
    />
```

And here's what I got:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=34810426) for Binding (hash=11882558)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'OpenCommand'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=34810426): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=34810426): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=34810426): Attach to WpfApplication1.TestControl.LoadCommand (hash=5114324)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=34810426): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=34810426): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=34810426): Activate with root item UserControlViewModel (hash=33108977)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=34810426):   At level 0 - for UserControlViewModel.OpenCommand found accessor <null>
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'OpenCommand' property not found on 'object' ''UserControlViewModel' (HashCode=33108977)'. BindingExpression:Path=OpenCommand; DataItem='UserControlViewModel' (HashCode=33108977); target element is 'TestControl' (Name=''); target property is 'LoadCommand' (type 'ICommand')
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=34810426): TransferValue - got raw value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=34810426): TransferValue - using fallback/default value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=34810426): TransferValue - using final value <null>
```

Here's what's happening: In `MainWindow.xaml`, `{StaticResource ViewModel}` is being looked up in the context of `TestControl`. The effect is the same as calling `FindResource` in `TestControl`:

```
public TestControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var x = FindResource("ViewModel");

    //  Set breakpoint here and inspect x
    ;
}
```

`TestControl` has its own resource with the key `ViewModel`, so that's what the lookup finds. That resource is a `UserControlViewModel` which has no `OpenCommand` property, and in that case it is *hiding* the completely different resource by the same name in `MainWindow`.

I don't know where you got this viewmodel resource scheme from, but you can see it's a serious mistake. Nobody in `MainWindow` should ever have to worry about what resource keys are used internally in `TestControl`.

Fortunately there's no need to create that problem. You can rip out a chunk of code and end up with something simpler and more robust as well as more maintainable.

So, to fix the problem:

First, don't create all your viewmodels as resources, because there's no reason to do it and it causes problems. Compare this `ExecuteCommand` binding to the one you had. What were you gaining with all that stuff? Nothing. If you're bothering to set the `DataContext`, *use it as a DataContext*.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <models:UserControlViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="_Load" IsDefault="True"
        Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=LoadCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:TestControl}}}"/>
</Grid>
```

And here's what `MainWindow` should look like (leaving out the `CommandBindings` thing that you don't really want):

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <models:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <!-- 
    local:TestControl.DataContext is its own viewmodel, so we use RelativeSource
    to get to the Window, and then we look at Window.DataContext for the main window
    viewmodel. 
    -->
    <local:TestControl 
        LoadCommand="{Binding DataContext.OpenCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
        />
</StackPanel>
```

Last of all, it's generally bad practice, for reasons which must now be all too obvious, for UserControls to create their own viewmodels. I find there's much less confusion when they inherit their parent's `DataContext`. But I've thrown enough of your design out the window for one day, so we'll leave that alone.

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer but I changed the `Command` and it didn't help. Also without "routing" the command through the `ViewModel` I cannot add some kind of automatic behavior like "really overwrite this file?" stuff. What really freaks me out is that if I just throw my `UserControl`on a `Window` and use the predefined `Open` command without any `ViewModel` everything works ... but if I try to make everything right, add a `ViewModel` and try to bind the LoadCommand to the Command of my `ViewModel` I can see in cody-behind of the `UserControl`that the `DependencyProperty` is empty.

Comment: And yes I defined a `DependencyProperty` on my `UserControl` and `DelegateCommand` on my `ViewModel`. The one on my `UserControl` is just to be able to add the `Binding` later in my `Window` on `XAML` level and to pass the `Command Binding` to the `ViewModel` where I declared it in order to add some monitoring and default behavior like the "The file does already exist" stuff.

Comment: On second thought, I think I may have guessed wrong about some of the code that you kept secret. Are you setting `DataContext = this;` in your UserControl? You need to share the full codebehind for the user control and show where the viewmodel is coming from. Is there actually a `StaticResource` somewhere called `ViewModel`? If so, where?

Comment: @dukemadcat I can't reconstruct your code from what you're telling me about your intent, and it's silly to try when you could just copy and paste. [I need enough code to recreate the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will break everything down tomorrow and post a complete and running code.

Comment: Many thanks for that detailed answer that not only told my what was wrong but why. That told me much more than I expected ;)